# Django throwing a ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, django

The whole error is quite huge :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "C:\Users\FiercePC\IdeaProjects\RadioShazam\server\ServerDjango\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\FiercePC\IdeaProjects\RadioShazam\server\ServerDjango\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 257, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 39, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.management.commands.runserver import (
  File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import (
  File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 14, in <module>
    from wsgiref import simple_server
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`
```

I just generated the project and didn't do almost anything. The program works on my computer but not on my friend's. We have the same versions of python/django etc.

Comment: Did you check the python version and installed packages versions?

Comment: I did, we have the same python version and we downloaded the same versions of the packages

Comment: You both might have same version of python and django but might be running differently using different python version despite  being same version installed and another reason could be your friend might not have activated the virtual environment.